# Limit quantity number for a stripe product

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently setting-up stripe for a SaaS company to be able to order recurrent products with a tiers price based on volume (see https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object-tiers_mode). I would like to limit the maximum number of units allowed (a user can only order up to 100 units and after the checkout is impossible). Has someone found a way to do it?
Thanks for your help,
Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that would be implemented by your integration, checked & enforced via your application logic. If your customer reaches 100 units, you would prevent them from increasing it or alternatively return an error from your server when they try to initiate payment.

Restricting quantity like you ask is not supported by the Stripe API.

Comment: That's what I was guessing but I wanted to be sure. Thanks for the confirmation.